# Show Item in drop down which is not in underlying DataSource

Tags: c#, combobox

I have a `ComboBox` control which is set to `DropDownList` as `DropDownStyle`. The control is initialed like below;

```
List<Sample> samples = new List<Sample>(){
    new Sample(),//Empty record
    new Sample(){Id = 1, Name = "Sample1"}, 
    new Sample(){Id = 2, Name = "Sample2"}};

// Bind the ComboBox to the list
this.comboBox1.DataSource = samples;
this.comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
this.comboBox1.ValueMember = "Id";
```

When I set, `this.comboBox1.Text = "Sample3";` the drop down doesn't show anything in the text area. It's obvious that `Sample3` is not in the underlying `DataSource` which is `samples` list.

My requirement is to show an item which not in the drop down, but the `DropDownStyle` set as `DropDownList`. Is it possible?

This is possible when using a `ComboBox` that has a `DropDownStyle` set to `DropDown`.

Note: [How do I set a ComboBox default *not in the drop down* when a list item begins with the same text as a drop down item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023323/how-do-i-set-a-combobox-default-not-in-the-drop-down-when-a-list-item-begins-w) is not related to the question because OP is using `ComboBox` that has a `DropDownStyle` set to `DropDown`.

Comment: How about updating binding source, samples in this case ?

Comment: Can't do that. If I can I won't ask this question. :-)

Comment: Agreed, I don't see any direct way (to my knowledge). Either avoiding datasource or modifying  datasource is the only options.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this concept by following code:

```
 DataTable dt = (DataTable)comboBox1.DataSource;
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Name"] = "Select";
        dr["ID"] = 0;

        dt.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0);
        comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Comment: Please see comments in the Question. I can't change the `DataSource`. If I can then no need for this question.